# MongoDB - How to access fields in the document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to do the following questions.

1. Find the ISBN and title of books that were published in 2022.
2. Find the ISBN, title of book, and publisher of books that have at least two authors and at most three authors.

[MongoDB subject.js](https://pastebin.com/g7ySAeFD)

For Question 1, I've tried:
I wanted to try to use `$eq` but I'm not so sure how to so I tried using `$elemMatch` but it seems like I have no idea how it works too.

```
db.Subject.aggregate( [
     {"$unwind":"$subject.book"},
     {"$match":{"subject.book":{"$elemMatch":{"subject.yearPub":2022}} }},
     {"$project":{"subject.book.ISBN":1,"subject.book.bookTitle":1 }}
])
```

For Question 2, I've tried:
This works so far it gives me books with 3 authors. But for some reason, it misses the books with 2 authors.

```
db.Subject.aggregate([{"$match": {"$or": [{'subject.book.author.3': {"$exists": true}},
{'book.author.2': {"$exists": true}}]}},
{"$project": {"subject.book.ISBN": 1,"subject.book.bookTitle": 1,"subject.book.publisher": 1,"_id":0}}
]).pretty()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: Filter with dot notation: "subject.book.yearPub"

```
db.Subject.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$subject.book"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "subject.book.yearPub": 2022
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "subject.book.ISBN": 1,
      "subject.book.bookTitle": 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo Q1 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aE7kACujapl)

**Updated: To filter the document in the array**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "subject.book.yearPub": 2022
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "subject.book": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$subject.book",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$this.yearPub",
              2022
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "subject.book.ISBN": 1,
      "subject.book.bookTitle": 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo Q1.1 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-z-V-FVm5Cy)

---

Q2: I suspect that you observe the result incorrectly. `subject.book.author.3` will return you the fourth element from the `subject.book.author` array as the index starts from 0.

For your current query, it will return the document with the third and fourth elements in the `subject.book.author` array which means that as long the array contains **more than 2** elements, the document will be returned.

Instead, you need the `$size` operator to get the size of the array. While there are documents that don't have the `book` property, so use `$ifNull` to return the empty array to prevent an error when using `$size`.

```
db.Subject.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $in: [
          {
            $size: {
              $ifNull: [
                "$subject.book.author",
                []
              ]
            }
          },
          [
            2,
            3
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "subject.book.ISBN": 1,
      "subject.book.bookTitle": 1,
      "subject.book.publisher": 1,
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo Q2 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QtPCEL9zsGz)

**Updated: To filter the document in the array**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $in: [
          {
            $size: {
              $ifNull: [
                "$subject.book.author",
                []
              ]
            }
          },
          [
            2,
            3
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "subject.book": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$subject.book",
          cond: {
            $in: [
              {
                $size: {
                  $ifNull: [
                    "$subject.book.author",
                    []
                  ]
                }
              },
              [
                2,
                3
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "subject.book.ISBN": 1,
      "subject.book.bookTitle": 1,
      "subject.book.publisher": 1,
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo Q2.1 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9gG3wx_BnES)

---

**Note: You attach too many questions into one. Please remember to split it into different questions (posts) when you ask a new question in the future.**

Comment: For question 1 would it be possible to group them together? 
I tried running a `{"$group":{"_id":"$subject.book.ISBN"}},`

Comment: For question 2 the output shouldn't not contain "Introduction to the Design and Analysis of Algorithms" and books containing "C++"

Comment: For Q1, you can use `$filter` without `$unwind` to filter the document in the array. [Demo Q1](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-z-V-FVm5Cy). For Q2, also use `$filter` to filter the document in the array. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9gG3wx_BnES).

Answer (score 1):

For Question 2, since Yong Shun mentioned array starts at 0, I've edited the code to fit accordingly. As well as if you want to collect each books as an individual record you will need to unwind them to the book level.
I hope this answers your question.
I'm new to MongoDB as well so let me know if it is not working as intended.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$subject.book"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$or": [
        {
          "subject.book.author.2": {
            "$exists": true
          }
        },
        {
          "subject.book.author.1": {
            "$exists": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "subject.book.ISBN": 1,
      "subject.book.bookTitle": 1,
      "subject.book.publisher": 1,
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Click [Q2 MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sZ__mvXLCa3)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$unwind` you can also use `$filter`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "subject.book": { $exists: true }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      book: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$subject.book",
          cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.yearPub", 2022 ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1mUHQKdcqna)